# Ruby array optimization code

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have such code in Ruby is it possible to write it shorter??

```
 first_name = person[0]
  last_name = person[1]
  person_id = person[2]
  email = person[3]
  title = person[4]
  phone = person[5]
  mobile = person[6]
  department = person[7]
  address = person[8]
  city = person[9]
  zip_code =person[10]
  state =person[11]
  country = person[12]
  manager_id = person[13]
```

Comment: This looks like `person` should be a hash to begin with.

Comment: Or, you know, a `Person`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

```
first_name, 
  last_name, 
  person_id, 
  email, 
  title, 
  phone, 
  mobile, 
  department, 
  address, 
  city, 
  zip_code, 
  state, 
  country, 
  manager_id = person
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > a = [1,2,3,4]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > v1, v2, v3, v4 = a
 => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :008 > puts v1, v2, v3, v4
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can write that piece of code in a shorter fashion, as @fuzzyalej and @Jörg have already demonstrated. But should you? It's very brittle, if at some time you decide to add a new datum in a new, different index in your `person` array, the existing code will break.

If possible, you should pack all person information in a class or a hash, instead.

Comment: Thanks @fuzzyalej, I edited my answer to include your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
first_name, last_name, person_id = person
```